# Mac OS Sonoma 14.3.1 with Xcode 15.2 build throws ld: library 'CocoaAsyncSocket' not found

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, cocoapods

I've Mac M2 chip. After my last weekend update of my Mac OS from Monterey to Sonoma (14.3) and upgrading the Xcode from 14.2 to Xcode 15.2, my react-native project code (0.72.4) build is failed, but after clearing node_modules, pods and reinstalling it worked.

Now i want create a new project for react native. I went to test by creating a new react native project using "npx react-native init ProjectName" with 0.73.5, my project is failed to build for ios. It throws

"❌ ld: library 'CocoaAsyncSocket' not found"

I tried doing all the below, but no use

- Remove derive data
- Delete build folder from ios
- pod deintegrate && pod install
- yarn cache clean
- close the metro bundler and restart
- Tried to build via command line and via Xcode, its all the same
- I tried to link the CocoaAsyncSocket in Xcode.

Can anyone give me some clue about what's going on. How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Try oppening app-name.xcodeproj instead of app-name.xcworkspace in xCode and build your app.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for helping me out. Really appreciate your help. I tried that, but unfortunately it didn't help me out even i was trying to build via Xcode. But what i noticed was when i ran the command react-native run-ios, i could see my device name and the booted simulator name appear like side by side. And I think it messed up the xcode build. So what i did was if I mention the simulator name it worked, "react-native run-ios --simulator iPhone 15 Pro".

Hope it helps someone out there.

Thanks,
BT